# How do I clear the view cache for a single file in express.js?

Tags: node.js, express, view, handlebars.js

when i render my homepage like this:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    res.render('../_cache/homepage-1.hbs', {
        title: 'Home',
        style: 'home-new',
        projectSlug: 'homepage',
    });
});
```

it seems to cache the way `homepage-1.hbs` was when the first started. if i then edit the file, it will still show the old one until i reboot the server. but only in production, it does not happen in development.

How can i clear this cache?

edit: apparently it is caused by the view engine, which for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/hbs

there is a cache built into this view engine, but not documention on how to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will

```
 const hbs = require('hbs');
 let fullPath = path.resolve('_cache/homepage-1.hbs');
 delete hbs.cache[fullPath];
```

this is how you delete stuff from the view cache in hbs.